# How do I programmatically set the preferred language for a user?

Tags: 8, users, i18n-l10n

I would like to update the preferred_langcode of a user as soon as he changes the language in a language switcher block.

I'm already aware of the `getPreferredLangcode` method mentioned in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!src!Entity!User.php/function/User%3A%3AgetPreferredLangcode/8.6.x and looking for a `setPreferredLangcode` method, if one exists.

If not, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 4):

Seems D8 doesn't have a `setPreferredLangcode` method yet. So, the preferred approach IMHO would be to use the default `set` method of D8 Entity API as below

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load('uid');
$user->set('preferred_langcode', 'en or whatever langcode we want');
$user->save();
```